# Unity3D. Индекс вне границы массива

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Есть массив игровых объектов, которые уничтожаются после столкновения с коллайдером. Есть код в виде цикла `for`, который проходит по каждому элементу массива и увеличивает `int` переменную на 1, если элемент массива равен `null`. Далее по коду, вызывается следующий метод, который передаёт `int` переменную в качестве параметра и внутри него сравнивается, если переданный параметр соответствует другой `int` переменной, то загружаем следующий уровень.

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что во время выполнения игры, когда запускается проверка элементов массива, Unity вызывает ошибку `Index was outside the bounds of the array`. Я со своей стороны не могу понять, с чем это связанно. Полный код скрипта ниже:

```
    [SerializeField]
    private int sumDeathSitizen, needToEndLvl; // Переменная sumDeathSitizen запоминает, сколько было уничтожено игровых объектов. needToEndLvl указывается внутри редактора Unity. Отвечает за то, сколько должно быть уничтожено игровых объектов
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] Victims; // Массив игровых объектов


    public void died (int d)
    {
        if (d == needToEndLvl)
        {
            loadNextScene();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Task not end");
        }
    }

    public void canEndLvl()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= needToEndLvl; i++)
        {
            if (Victims[i] == null)
            {
                sumDeathSitizen = sumDeathSitizen + 1;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("EndSum");
        died(sumDeathSitizen);
    }

    private void loadNextScene()
    {
        int scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        scene = scene + 1;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(scene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
```

По задумке, когда игрок выполняет или не выполняет определённые действия по уничтожению игровых объектов, необходимо подойти к двери и попытаться открыть её. Когда выполняется действие открытие двери, сперва вызывается метод `canEndLvl()` который, как описывалось выше, проходит циклом `for` по массиву игровых элементов. Если все объекты уничтожены, то текущая сцена заканчивается и загружается следующая. Как я уже говорил выше, не смотря на то, что результат при уничтожении объектов суммируется верный, Unity упирается в строчку if `(Victims[i] == null)` с ошибкой `Index was outside the bounds of the array` и не передаёт значение дальше для сравнения и загрузки нового уровня. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @ValeryLosev ОТЛИЧНО!) Вынесите ваш комментарий в ответ и я помечу его правильным ответом:)

Comment: Бегло прочитал вопрос, так и не понял почему Вы используете не коллекцию а массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял `needToEndLvl` показывает количество объектов, которое надо уничтожить, например 4. И, например, у вас 4 игровых объекта в массиве. Тогда у вас ошибка в цикле, в последней итерации вы обращаетесь к `Victims[4]`, т.е. к 5 элементу, которого не существует.
 Надо так: `for (int i = 0; i < needToEndLvl; i++)`